# air-datepicker js : hour+2

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, timepicker

I try to set hours (+2h) to actual day and not for the others.

Example:

Today is October 18th, time: 10am.

- If I click (without changing the date) -> Time is 12pm.
- If I click and choose tomorrow (19th October) -> I choose any time.

Today is October 19th, time: 08am.

- If I click (without changing the date) -> Time is 10am.
- If I click and choose tomorrow (20th October) -> I choose any time.

PS : If possible, I want to disable the entry in the input (because we can change the time)

Thx

```js
    var start = new Date()
 var hour = start.getHours()+2;

 
 $('#date').datepicker({
        language: 'en',
  timepicker: true,
  minHours: hour
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<input type='text' id="date" class="" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I thought you want to disable previous dates (everything < now + 2hours). If not, just change `minDate: start` to `startDate: start`.

Try with:

```js
var start = new Date();

// first available date and time
start.setHours(start.getHours() + 2);

$('#date').datepicker({
  language: 'en',
  timepicker: true,
  minDate: start,
  onSelect: function(fd, d, picker) {
    if (d < start) {
      return;
    }

    if (d.getDate() == start.getDate() &&
      d.getMonth() == start.getMonth() &&
      d.getYear() == start.getYear()) {
      // set minHours to start hours
      picker.update({
        minHours: start.getHours()
      });
    } else {
      // set minHours to 0 hours
      picker.update({
        minHours: 0
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input type='text' id="date" class="" />
```

Also, air-timepicker docs: http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/

Comment: Thank you for your help it's perfect ! :)